# Facebook graph api:  Inconsistent tagged videos data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all tagged videos of myself using the facebook graph api. when i click on the link below (which is the link from the [FB Graph API docs site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to get tagged videos)

https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos?access_token=... etc

it shows all the tagged videos of myself that i have uploaded and my friends have uploaded

However, when i try the same query through my fb app, it only shows tagged videos that i have uploaded. I can't see the videos that my friends have uploaded that have myself tagged in them.

I do have the following permission accepted for my app as well:

```
friends_photo_video_tags, user_photo_video_tags, user_videos, friends_videos
```

and here is my code i use to query the tagged videos from my app (which is the same from the link above):

```
$arr_fb_user_videos  = $this->facebook->api("/me/videos");      
var_dump("<pre>",$arr_fb_user_videos,"</pre>");
```

any help?

Comment: did you try running "/me/permissions" to confirm the permissions are getting set?

Comment: @ldg - I tried, and they are all set properly.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest to use FQL query to fetch data from facebook.

Here is the sample code for fetching tags from video.

```
$fql = "SELECT subject FROM video_tag WHERE vid='{$vid}' ";

$params = array(
                'method' => 'fql.query',
                'query' => $fql,
                'access_token'=>$access_token
               );

$video_tags = $this->facebook->api($params);

where,
$vid is video_id
```

Comment: this query only allows me to fetch a video where i already have the video id. I want to grab all the videos where i am tagged in. I think it just might be a fb bug

Comment: for that you can use your uid to query vid and then for each vid you can find friends tagged in the video. 

Thanks